# PSTCollectionVIew - Unable to build with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, pstcollectionview

I use PSTCollectionView in my app and it work great when I build with Xcode 4.6.3. But I cant build it with Xcode 5 because the following reason:

```
 error: Class Unavailable: UICollectionView on iOS versions prior to 6.0
```

Help me to fix this issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please look at the above screenshot from Apple's documentation, which clearly says [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) Only available iOS 6 and above.

**I think you are having deployment target as < iOS6. That is the problem.Change it and try again**

**Updates:**

I referred PSTCollectionView [here](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) which clearly mentions about your older version support. **You should use PSUICollectionView instead of that**. Refer the attached screenshot.

[image]